# Как написать программу для скачивания файла?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

Как сделать так, что бы по нажатию кнопки, программа скачала файл по адресу который я написал в `TextBox`?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
using System.Net;

var uri = new Uri(@"https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/e4/7_Collection_Eybl_Great_Britain_-_E._Kealey_-_Women_of_Britain_say_%E2%80%93_GO.jpg"); // Путь откуда скчивать
var fileName = Path.GetFileName(uri.AbsolutePath); // Только имя скачиваемого имя файла (без пути)
var destinationDir = "c:\\"; // Папка в которую скачивать

WebClient wc = new WebClient();
wc.Proxy = null;
wc.DownloadFile(uri, Path.Combine(destinationDir, fileName));
```

Comment: Подчеркнул Path

Comment: @May_be попробуйте добавить вначале `using System.IO;`

Comment: An unhandled exception of type 'System.Net.WebException' occurred in System.dll

Additional information: Исключение во время запроса WebClient.

Comment: @May_be рискну предположить, что не существует папка в которую вы пытаетесь скачать файл. Либо существует, но по какой-то причине создать в ней файл нельзя (например, права доступа). Еще может быть у вас слишком мудрёная ссылка, которая не заканчивается именем файла. По-этому функция `Path.GetFileName(uri.AbsolutePath)` возвращает пустую строку и далее конечно же не удается создать файл с пустым именем. Посмотрите есть ли в вашем эксепшене InnerException, вдруг это поможет. Наконец это может оказаться какая-то проблема с сетью.